# Adding default value to dropdown in jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have cascading dropdowns. On the selection of one dropdown, another dropdown binds using ajax. This works completely but i want that the second dropdown should also contain default text and value like ('Select me'). How can i add this default value. This is my code.

```
   function BindCities(drpstate) {
        var stateid = $(drpstate).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Register.aspx/BindCities',
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{"id":"' + stateid + '"}',
            success: function (result) {
                var drpcity = $('.drpcity');
                drpcity.empty();
                $.each(result.d, function () {
                    drpcity.append(
                        $('<option/>', {
                            value: this.id,
                            text: this.name

                        })
                    );
                });

            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="drpstate" onchange="BindCities(this)" ID="drpdwnState">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select State" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="drpcity" ID="drpdwnCity">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select City" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Server side code:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static List<CountryState> BindCities(int id)
    {
        EkbnManager em = new EkbnManager();
        List<City> cities = em.GetCityByStateId(id);

        List<CountryState> countrystate = new List<CountryState>();
        foreach (var item in cities)
        {
            CountryState cnt = new CountryState();
            cnt.name = item.Name;
            cnt.id = item.Id;
            countrystate.Add(cnt);
        }

        return countrystate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In success function do like this:

```
    success: function (result) {
                    var drpcity = $('.drpcity');
                    drpcity.empty();
                     drpcity.append(
                            $('<option/>', {
                                value: -1,
                                text: please select one

                            })
                    $.each(result.d, function () {
                        drpcity.append(
                            $('<option/>', {
                                value: this.id,
                                text: this.name

                            })
                        );
                    });
```

Comment: I had one more question. As i am using ajax for binding dropdowns. Whenever i select a particular value, i always get selected value as 0 on server side? how can i access the selected value of the ajax binded dropdown server side?

Comment: Do i need to use hidden field?

Comment: as its populated via ajax on client side so you may be not able to access selected value from server side, yes you can use hidden field to keep track of selected value, BTW why you not use ajax control toolkit's casacaded dropdown?

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebService.asmx/GetMethod",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#drpName").empty();
                $("<option value='-1'>(Select item)</option>").appendTo("#drpName");
                $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                    $("#drpName").append($("<option></option>").val(value.ID).html(value.Title));
                });
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Could not get!");
            }
        });
```